# How to create a streak from an array of tuples in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, tuples

I have an array of tuples that looks like:

```
[("07-20-2016", 2), ("07-22-2016", 5.0), ("07-21-2016", 3.3333333333333335)]
```

It consists of a String that is a date and a Double that is a mood (Moods less than or equal to 3 means that day was a good day).
I am trying to figure out how to create a streak of good days.

So what I think I need to do first is sort the array of tuples to put them in order by date.
Then I need to count the tuples that are below the mood value 3 if they are in a row. In this case the result would be 1 because there is only 1 day that is below 3.

If I had an array of tuples like:

```
[("07-22-2016", 5.0), ("07-21-2016", 3), ("07-20-2016", 2), ("07-19-2016", 1), ("07-18-2016", 1), ("07-16-2016", 2), ("07-15-2016", 3)]
```

It would have a result of 4 because the highest number of days in a row that are below 3 is 4. The reason it wouldn't be 6 is because a date of "07-17-2016" doesn't exist.

Please help me solve this problem. I know there are many users on here that are smarter then me. Can you solve this?

Comment: Less than 3 or less than _or equal to_ 3?

Comment: This would be a lot easier and nicer if you were not using tuples. Why isn't this thing a lightweight struct? And for that matter, why aren't your dates Dates? You're not going to be a happy programmer if you distance your data models so far from your intended purpose.

Comment: @tktsubota Less than or equal to 3.

Comment: @matt I am sorry. I am new to this and i am trying to do things right. The reason its a an array of tuples is because I already did this to average entires of the same day.

    var statsTupleArray = [(date: String, value: Int)]()

    var dict = [String: [Double]]()

    statsTupleArray.forEach {(date, num) in dict[date] = (dict[date] ?? []) + [Double(num)]}

    let averagedStatsTupleArrayResult = dict.map {(date, nums) in (date, nums.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(nums.count))}

Comment: Well that was a bad array and this is a bad array. If your app relies upon an association of a date and a score, that ought to be a struct permeating your app.

Comment: @matt I am sorry I am not that smart. You seem like a genius. How would I fix it the way you are talking about?

Comment: It's not about smart. You do that in your question too and I don't like it. It's about planning ahead and using good programming practices. Stop putting yourself down and think about the advice you get. This is about getting things done and growing and learning, not about ranking people.

Comment: Right now I am getting all the updates of the users and doing a for loop that looks like:
    
for update in updates {
                self.statsTupleArray += [(date: monthDayYearDateFormatter.stringFromDate(update.created_at!), value: update.moodValue)]
 }

Comment: Why don't you just use `update.created_at` instead of the string representation?

Comment: I ask you again: since this is about dates, why on earth would you turn them into strings for storage? Dates can be compared for date order. Strings are a massive indirection away from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first build an array of streaks of good and bad moods, and then filter or reduce it to analyse the streeks:

```
 let dateData = [("07-22-2016", 5.0), ("07-21-2016", 3), ("07-20-2016", 2), ("07-19-2016", 1), ("07-18-2016", 1), ("07-16-2016", 2), ("07-15-2016", 3)]

 var streaks:[(String,Bool,Int)] = []
 for (date,value) in dateData
 {
   if let goodMood = streaks.last?.1
      where goodMood == (value < 3)
   { streaks[streaks.count-1].2 += 1 }
   else
   { streaks += [(date, value<3, 1)] }
 }

 // at this point streaks contains an array of tupples with counts of consecutive days of a given mood
 //
 // [("07-22-2016", false, 2), ("07-20-2016", true, 4), ("07-15-2016", false, 1)]
 //
 // you can then process that as you need

 let goodStreaks = streaks.filter{$0.1}.map{($0.0,$0.2)}  // [("07-20-2016", 4)]
 let badStreaks  = streaks.filter{!$0.1}.map{($0.0,$0.2)} // [("07-22-2016", 2), ("07-15-2016", 1)]
 let longestGoodStreak  = streaks.filter{$0.1}.reduce(0, combine: { max($0,$1.2) }) // 4
```

Answer (score 3):

First, as matt suggested, make a nicer datatype. The language makes this super convenient with structs. We need each entry to have a date and a mood score. Easy-peasy.

```
import Foundation

struct JournalEntry {
    let date: NSDate
    let score: Double

    var isGoodDay: Bool { return self.score <= 3.0 }
}
```

(The computed `isGoodDay` property will make life even easier later on.)

Now we need to turn the raw list of tuples into a list of these structs. That's straightforward. Create a date parser, and use `map` to convert between the tuple type and the struct:

```
typealias RawEntry = (String, Double)
func parseRawEntries<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == RawEntry>
                    (rawEntries: S)
    -> [JournalEntry]
{
    let parser = NSDateFormatter()
    parser.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    // Use guard and flatMap because dateFromString returns an Optional; 
    // you might prefer to throw an error to indicate that the data are 
    // incorrectly formatted
    return rawEntries.flatMap { rawEntry in
        guard let date = parser.dateFromString(rawEntry.0) else {
            return nil
        }
        return JournalEntry(date: date, score: rawEntry.1)
    }
}
```

After converting we'll need to go through the list testing two conditions: first, that days are "good" and then that pairs of good days are consecutive. We have that helper method in the data structure itself to test the former. Let's create another helper function for the consecutive part:

```
/* N.B. for brevity this assumes first and second are already sorted! */
func entriesConsecutive(first: JournalEntry, _ second: JournalEntry) -> Bool {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let dayDiff = calendar.components(.Day,
                                      fromDate: first.date,
                                      toDate: second.date,
                                      options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
    return dayDiff.day == 1
}
```

At each enumeration step, we'll have the current entry, but we also need either the previous or the next, so that we can test for consecutivity. We also obviously want to keep track of the streaks' counts as we find them. Let's make another datatype for that. (The reason for `lastEntry` rather than `nextEntry` will be clear in a moment.)

```
struct Streak {
    let lastEntry: JournalEntry
    let count: UInt
}
```

This is the fun part: iterating over the array, constructing `Streak`s. This can be done with a `for` loop. But consuming sequences by calculation and agglomeration on each new item is a known pattern. It's called "[folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))"; Swift uses the alternate term `reduce()`.

Reducing a sequence into groups, or while keeping track of something, is also a well-known pattern: the combined value is itself a collection. At each step, you inspect the new item along with the most recent value in the reduction. The new value for the reduction -- what you return from the combining function -- is still the collection, either with the previous value updated or a new value appended.

The `Streak` datatype from above will make the elements in the reduction: that's why it uses the *last* entry. Each step, we will save the `JournalEntry` and inspect it on the next.

For streaks, we only care about "good" days. Let's make life simple and `filter` the list right off the bat: `let goodDays = journal.filter { $0.isGoodDay }` We'll need the first entry so that there's something to compare to on the first step. This is also a chance to bail out if for some reason there *are* no good days.

```
guard let firstEntry = goodDays.first else {
    return []
}
```

That first entry goes into a `Streak` object, which goes into the collection that will become the reduction: `let initial = [Streak(lastEntry: firstEntry, count: 1)]`, and we're ready to go. The full function looks like this (I'll let the comments explain the procedure inside the reduce):

```
func findStreaks(in journal: [JournalEntry]) -> [Streak] {
    let goodDays = journal.filter { $0.isGoodDay }
    guard let firstEntry = goodDays.first else {
        return []
    }
    let initial = [Streak(lastEntry: firstEntry, count: 1)]
    return 
        // The first entry is already used; skip it.
        goodDays.dropFirst()
                .reduce(initial) { 
                  (reduction: [Streak], entry: JournalEntry) in
                    // Get most recent Streak for inspection
                    let streak = reduction.last!    // ! We know this exists

                    let consecutive = entriesConsecutive(streak.lastEntry, 
                                                         entry)
                    // If this is the same streak, increment the count by
                    // replacing the previous value.
                    // Otherwise add a new Streak with count 1.
                    let newCount = consecutive ? streak.count + 1 : 1
                    let streaks = consecutive ? 
                                  Array(reduction.dropLast()) :
                                  reduction
                    return streaks + 
                            [Streak(lastEntry: entry, count: newCount)]
                }
}
```

Now, back at the top level, things are very simple. Raw data:

```
let rawEntries = [("07-22-2016", 5.0), ("07-21-2016", 3), ("07-20-2016", 2), ("07-19-2016", 1), ("07-18-2016", 1), ("07-16-2016", 2), ("07-15-2016", 3)]
```

Convert that into the relevant datatype, immediately sorting by date while we're at it.

```
let journal = parseRawEntries(rawEntries).sort { $0.date < $1.date }
```

Calculate streaks:

```
let streaks = findStreaks(in: journal)
```

And the result you want is then `let bestStreakLen = streaks.map({ $0.count }).maxElement()`

---

(Small note: comparing `NSDate` using `<` like that requires a new function:

```
func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    let earlier = lhs.earlierDate(rhs)
    return earlier == lhs
}
```

)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer I found.

```
func datesToStreaks(input: [NSDate]) -> [[NSDate]] {
        var ranges:[[NSDate]] = [[]]
        input.forEach { currentDay in
            var lastRange = ranges.last ?? []
            if let lastDate = lastRange.last {
                if lastDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(86400).isEqualToDate(currentDay) {
                    lastRange.append(currentDay)
                    ranges.removeLast()
                    ranges.append(lastRange)
                }
                else {
                    ranges.append([currentDay])
                }
            }
            else {
                lastRange.append(currentDay)
                ranges.removeLast()
                ranges.append(lastRange)
            }

        }
        return ranges
    }


    let input = [("07-22-2016", 5.0), ("07-21-2016", 3), ("07-20-2016", 2), ("07-19-2016", 1), ("07-18-2016", 1), ("07-16-2016", 2), ("07-15-2016", 3)]
    let sortedDays:[NSDate] = input
        .filter { (date, mood) in
            mood <= 3.0}
        .map { (date, mood) in
            return date}
        .flatMap{ date in
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            return dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)
        }
        .sort{$0.0.earlierDate($0.1).isEqualToDate($0.0)}

    let maxStreak = datesToStreaks(sortedDays)
        .map{$0.count}
        .reduce(0, combine: {return max($0,$1)})

    print(maxStreak) // 4
```